# Php contact form post value error

Tags: php, forms, curl

When i send this contact form $subject[], it post takes only first digit.
Example : when i choose "Pol Center Plaza", it post "Flora Suite Office" or when choose "Villa Fenerion", it post "Hukukcular Towers".

```html
<p class="sec">
    <select name="subject" placeholder="Lokasyon Tercihiniz">
        <option value="1">Flora Suite Office</option>
        <option value="2">Hukukçular Towers</option>
        <option value="3">Elhamra İş Hanı</option>
        <option value="6">EGS Business Park</option>
        <option value="7">Beybi Giz</option>
        <option value="8">Oyal İş Merkezi</option>
        <option value="9">Akasya Tower Residence</option>
        <option value="11">Pol Center Plaza</option>
        <option value="12">Mall of İstanbul</option>
        <option value="13">Folkart Towers</option>
        <option value="14">Milenyum İş Merkezi</option>
        <option value="15">Tepe Prime</option>
        <option value="16">Next Level</option>
        <option value="17">Skyport</option>
        <option value="19">Office 11</option>
        <option value="20">Villa Fenerion</option>
        <option value="24">Nart Center</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"binalar\":$subject[0],\"dil\":1}"
```

Comment: **No it does not** All that you will see in the `$_POST['subject']` is numbers. The numbers that you put in the `value="2"` attribute

Answer (score 1):

hi i think you should remove [] bracket from post just take $subject =$_POST['subject']; 100% your selected value you can get.

Answer (score -1):

```
$text=$_POST['text'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$surname=$_POST['surname'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$subject2=$_POST['subject2'];
$domain=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$ipadress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

I always add this but didn't work